# Clang-tidy change hungarian notation prefixes

Tags: c, clang, lint, clang-tidy, hungarian-notation

The coding standards of a project I am working on require a `_` as a separator between the Hungarian notation prefix and the variable name. For example:

```
uint32_t u32_MyVar;
```

By default `clang-tidy` formats it like so:

```
uint32_t u32MyVar;
```

How can I change the Hungarian notation prefix to include an underscore?

P.S. I tried using a variable prefix, but that is put before the Hungarian notation (i.e. `_u32MyVar`).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - I needed to change the style of the notation to `LowerCase` (possible values are `Off`, `On`, `LowerCase` and `CamelCase`. To do this add the following option:

```yaml
readability-identifier-naming.VariableHungarianPrefix: LowerCase
```

However, I also found out how to change the prefixes themselves by looking at the sources:

- https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/IdentifierNamingCheck_8cpp_source.html#l00748
- https://clang.llvm.org/extra/doxygen/IdentifierNamingCheck_8cpp_source.html#l00493

```yaml
readability-identifier-naming.HungarianNotation.PrimitiveType.uint32_t: myPrefix32
```